# How the image comes on the top of the above row in one div

Tags: html, css

I am working on the footer. On the right side down -image is attached- I have an image with a responsive "subscribe" button.[image] There is one dive with one general row.This general row consists of two different rows.
The first row includes two grids: col-lg-4  / col-lg-8 (white background)
The second one includes three grids:col-lg-4 / col-lg-4 / col-lg-4 (black background)
I want to put the image in the second row in the very right grid which comes on the top of the very right grid in the first row. 
the problem is although the image is put in the second row but it appears in the first row ! I want to correct it as the pattern [image]

```
<div class="container-fluid p0 hidden-xs  hidden-sm" style="border: solid yellow">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 ">
      <div class="row pb+ pt+ footer-border ">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
          <div class="container">
            <!-- brand starts -->
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 hidden-xs  pl0">
               <a href="/">
                   <i class=" icon-famousLogo icon-color famous-large "></i>
               </a>
            </div>
            <!-- brand ends -->

             <!-- Social Sharing Start -->
            <div class="col-lg-8  col-md-8 hidden-xs   clearfix">
              <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-offset-7 pt-">
                <ul class="list-inline float-r">
                  <li>
                    <span class="follow-us pr">FOLLOW US</span>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/famousmagazine">
                      <i class=" icon-facebook icon-color facebook pr "></i>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/famousweekly ">
                      <i class=" icon-twitter icon-color twitt pr"></i>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/famousweekly/ ">
                      <i class=" icon-instagram icon-color instagram"></i>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                    <!-- They are supposed to be add later after getting the right URL-->
              <!--<li >
                    <a  href="https://www.youtube.com">
                      <i class=" icon-youtube icon-color youtube"></i>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li >
                    <a href="https://www.instagram.com" >
                      <i class=" icon-Pintrest icon-color pint"></i>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li >
                    <a href="https:https://twitter.com" >
                      <i class=" icon-tumblr icon-color twitt"></i>
                    </a>
                  </li> -->
                  <!-- Hidden Social Sharing Ends-->
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
             <!-- Social Sharing Ends -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
       <!-- Second Row  / Footer Lists Starts -->
      <div class="row  hidden-xs  hidden-sm">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 ">
            <div class="bottomMenu-parent" >
              <div class="container">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 pl0 pt+ pb+" >
                  <table class="footer-table">
                    <tr>
                      <td><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></td>
                      <td class="pl++"><a href="#">CoNTACT US</a></td>
                    <tr>
                      <td><a href="#">TERMS AND CONDITIONS</a></td>
                      <td class="pl++"><a href="#">ADVERTISE</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><a href="#">PRIVACY POLICY</a></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div> 
                <!-- Sign up Starts -->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                </div>     
                <!--Sign Up Ends  -->
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                   <figure class="p pb0 footer-image">
                      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTPZA23BVynjg91p0lXTn2yEiCft5VkK70063kgELaL_77gtH_TWg">
                  </figure>
                  <a href="#" class="subscribe-button" >
                    <button type="button" >
                      SUBSCRIBE <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
                    </button>
                  </a> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
       <!-- Second Row / Footer List  Ends -->
    </div>
  </div>       
</div>

@media(min-width: @screen-sm-min) {

    .follow-us{
        color:@mainpink;
        .font-family(@font-Oswald-Bold) ;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    .footer-border{
        border: 1px solid @mainpink;
    }

    .footer-table{
        color:@white !important;
        text-align: left;
        tr{
            td{
                padding-bottom:10px;
                a{
                    .font-family(@font-SourceSansPro-Regular) !important;
                    color:@white !important;
                    text-transform: uppercase;
                    font-size:14px;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    .footer-image{
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you create a snippet or bin with that?

Comment: I have already attached images !

Comment: Yes, but part of the process to help you include debugging and "playing" with the code. That's why we need this. Maybe we can create it by ourself but I think that you should do it. (Read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) aspecially _"Help others reproduce the problem"_)

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the codes as below then it works :

```
.footer-image
{
     margin-top: -100px;
     bottom: 0px;
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center;
     padding-bottom:0px;
}
```